# Freezing after suspend, installing Nvidia driver worked on 16.04 but doesn't on 18.04

Tags: nvidia, suspend, 18.04

I found the same problem when I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but when I installed the Nvidia driver the problem was solved. But the same thing didn't work on 18.04 LTS

I have installed the last version of Nvidia driver but my laptop is still freezing.

What else can I try?

Comment: My Dell has Intel graphics and exhibits the same behavior. I don't think it's a graphics driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem plague me ... and a fix after many attempts was to re-install Ubuntu 18.04, and now it is working perfectly. I am also using Nvidia's "tested" Driver, as Nvidia was the culprit before.

Perhaps it was the "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers" ppa which installed "Extra" Stuff from the PPA and/or the 396 driver itself which screwed up my laptop's hibernating ability.

Either way it works flawlessly at this time of writing with the NVidia's 390 tested driver.  And just FYI, it was also working with the 396 driver for a long time, but became problematic last week - AGAIN!  SO although I don't know the exact cause  ...

It is/was definitely related to the NVidia driver as before switching to the Nouveau driver also worked, but I sure did not like that option.

Trying to help, Mark